# nix gives `No space left on device` even though /nix has lots

Tags: nix

I'm getting `No space left on device` when building (dependencies of) a nix project, even though both `/nix` and `/tmp` have >10G of space. I saw somewhere it might be using `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` (/run/user/1000) which is just 1.6G, but how would I increase the size of that / tell nix not to use it?

(This is on Ubuntu, not NixOS.)

EDIT: Fixed by `export TMPDIR=/tmp` (where /tmp has lots of space) and `nix-shell --impure …`. It seems nix builds stuff in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` (a tmpfs) if TMPDIR isn't set, but will use TMPDIR if set, so that worked around it.

Comment: Is your tmp folder in tmpfs?

Comment: You should post the full output of `df -h` and `mount`.  Also, more context for the error might help.  Also, depending on what you're building, maybe you need more than 10 GB of space: what is name of the derivation that failed to build due to running out of space?

Comment: @unhammer Thanks! I was scratching my head as to why I stumbled upon this error on my laptop since, on my desktop, the single-installation method is working correctly, and it is precisely what you commented. I'd instead go with Determinate's installer (running an OSTree-based Fedora Kinoite here), but right now, it is badly messing up the SELinux policy in `/var`, breaking SDDM. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

`df -h` and `df -ih` (you can run out of inodes, especially small filesystems with ext4)